# Logic Translating into Symbols

Tags: logic, logic-translation

Can someone help translate  “$(x^2)−1$  is  even  for  every  odd  integer $x$”  into  symbols.

I'm a bit lost, my train of though led me to:

$$∀x ∈ Z, x = ? ⇒ ?$$

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe it would be along the lines more like: (x^2)-1 = 2k for ∀x = 2k+1 maybe?

Comment: $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}, 2\nmid x\implies2\mid\left(x^2-1\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that depending on which symbols you prefer and if you need a low order logic or a more high level description:

- $\forall x\in\mathbb Z,\ x\equiv 1\pmod 2\implies x^2-1\equiv 0\pmod 2$
- $x\in2\mathbb Z+1\implies x^2-1\in2\mathbb Z$
- $\forall x\bigg( \exists k\in\mathbb Z\ :\ x=2k+1\implies \exists m\in\mathbb Z\ :\ x^2-1=2m\bigg)$
- $\forall x\in\mathbb Z,\ (-1)^x<0\implies(-1)^{x^2-1}>0$
- let $f:x\mapsto x^2-1$ then $f(2\mathbb Z+1)\subset2\mathbb Z$

And you can probably invent some more...

Comment: The bullet before the last is nice, I mean the one with exponents of $(-1)$

Comment: The $3^{rd}$ would benefit with a pair of brackets. It is somewhat ambiguous as to whether $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is part of the antecedent or not at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\forall x:\bigg(\underbrace{(\exists m \in \mathbb Z:x = 2m+1)}_{x\text{ is odd integer}} \to \underbrace{(\exists n\in \mathbb Z:x^2-1=2n)}_{x^2-1\text{ is even integer}}\bigg)
$$